# Create a checkerboard plot with unbalanced rows and colums

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset similar to this format `X = [[1,4,5], [34,70,1,5], [43,89,4,11], [22,76,4]]` where the length of element lists are not equal.

I want to create a checkerboard plot of 4 rows and 4 columns and the colorbar of each unit box corresponds to the value of the number. In this dataset some small boxes will be missing (eg. 4th column firs row).

How would I plot this in python using matplotlib?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use seaborn library or matplotlib to generate heatmap. Firstly, convert it to pandas dataframe to handle missing values.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,4,5],[34,70,1,5], [43,89,4,11],[22,76,4]])
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

Result looks something like this.
[image]